# Restore-SPFarm : Cannot find the proper backup files to restore. Verify that the directory name is valid and that the backup file exists

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, administration, backup, restore

I have backuped a sharepoint 2013 web application from my development environment, which created the following :-

1. XML file named spbrtoc
2. And a folder contain .bak files named spbr0001.
   So on my staging environemtn I run the following SP power sheeel command to restore the backup file to my staging environment  :-

   Restore-SPFarm -Directory C:\Users\user\Desktop\spbr0001 -RestoreMethod Overwrite -Item spbr0001 -BackupId dc3357f0-97d6-495f-83df-7d5cf5419729 –Verbose

But I will get the following error :-
**Restore-SPFarm : Cannot find the proper backup files to restore. Verify that the directory name is valid and that the backup file exists.**

So can anyone advice. And o make sure I am backuping the right file, I have re-write the power shell command to be refer to the xml file asfollow:-

```
Restore-SPFarm -Directory C:\Users\user\Desktop\spbrtoc.xml -RestoreMethod Overwrite -Item spbr0001 -BackupId dc3357f0-97d6-495f-83df-7d5cf5419729 –Verbose
```

But this ill raise the following error:-

**Restore-SPFarm : Directory C:\Users\user\Desktop\spbrtoc.xml does
not exist or the SQL Server service account and the AD-TDMGROUP\user
service account do not have permission to read or write to the backup folder.
Specify a different directory or ensure that the SharePoint Timer service and
Microsoft SQL Server service accounts have Full Control permission on both the
file share and the underlying folder.
At line:1 char:1
+ Restore-SPFarm -Directory C:\Users\user\Desktop\spbrtoc.xml
-RestoreMe ...**

Comment: If your path contains for example blank space (I see your example does not, but if it really does), you should enclose it in quotes

Comment: no it does not , but should i be referring to the .xml file or to the folder which contain .bak files ?

Comment: Aim for the .bak file

Answer (score 2):

Take your spbr0001 out of the directory path. SharePoint fills that in automatically.

Comment: you guys should mark this as an answer